# Issue with smooth shading

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-view, geometry

[image]

What you'll see is flat shading then smooth shading. It is splitting the object down the middle in a disection for soem reason, in regards to shade and lighting.

This effect carries over into other programs when exported as well.

*I made this object from a cube and used a boolean to make the cutouts.*

[image]

Comment: Hi. Can you show a screen shot in edit mode (in order to see what has been done by the boolean)

Comment: Hi lemon, here you go : https://gyazo.com/894fd40ceb65481b88e900c894169afc

Comment: ok... so... big bad ngons... have a try (on a copy of your object) : in edit mode, select all, then ctrl+T. That will show you the "real" geometry. Please again, send a screen shot of it

Comment: Here you go lemon : https://gyazo.com/bc6a81c591ccfce20433385be9e9c3fb

Comment: ok... I am not able to explain it technically speaking, but what you see here is the cause of your problem. Rendering systems (SL or even Blender) does not like such ngons because the inner geometry is not regular at all. So AFAIK, you need to correct it manually or model it from scratch respecting as far as possible some topology principles. To say it differently, boolean seems to be an easy way but it has such consequences.

Comment: What you can try (but not sure it will work) : start with a more subdivided cube and then apply the boolean with your "cutting shape". That will localize the holes a bit more and you can hope to have less distortions.

Comment: other possibility (simplier if it works here) : in edit mode, select the inner "ring" faces and set smooth only on it (so not in object mode but in edit mode : you find that in the shading/UVs tab of the tools panel)

Comment: Thank you lemon, just to clarify, when you say fix it manually, do you mean to remove as many of those many inner edges as possible?

Comment: I mean having ideally quads only (faces of 4 vertices) and as regular as possible. Some technics here (or other equivalent) can help https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bc52fcrHvAA

Comment: Thank you lemon, just one more question, if I try and dissolve or delete an edge and it says "invalid boundary region to join faces"
Does that mean that particular edge is 100% needed for the object to stay in it's current shape?

Comment: my answer will be : "probably"... (I am not sure in fact)

Comment: No worries lemon, just an update on my work so far. I decided on the manual rout as im not in the frame of mind for really, learningand don't mind the length of time it takes... This is what I have ; https://gyazo.com/c53305a78d4217612c279f48defe005a

Everywhere else looks great on that side (to me anyway) bar those three edges coming from that lower right corner. I cant delete two of them and the one I can creates ... this : https://gyazo.com/9d694807a7c043316d5e36c7513cfafe

I think i JUST figured how to fix that actually.

Comment: Hey lemon, for some reason, after I ctrl T to see the teleometry, it messes some parts up, like, removes and edge here and there and I found whilst fixing those, any edges I had removed, all sprung back up again... So in the end I just tried a little bit at a time and whilst the odd shadowing went away on the outside it stayed on the decorative bits. 

Also, this only seems to happen, when i view materials and rendering.

I'll take a look at your YT link soon.

Comment: probably you went back to object mode and ctrl+Z. At object mode level 'undo' will step back to the last state in object mode. So what have been edited (edit mode) in between is undo'ed'

Answer (score 2):

A possible approach to do it with quads only :

- Start with a square and subdivide it <kbd>W</kbd> then subdivide
- Extrude <kbd>E</kbd> and scale down <kbd>S</kbd>
- Make a copy and round it to sphere (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> then move the mouse to the right)
- Keep only the wanted vertices it each
- Move back the angular part and align it : set the cursor as pivot point, select the vertices then scale <kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>0</kbd> and for the other part <kbd>S</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd><kbd>0</kbd>
- Remove doubles

[image]

Concerning the shading, that may be dependent on your target system (sL ?)... so you may need to give it a try.

Possibilities :

- Global smooth
- Inner edge loop smooth
- Global smooth + edgesplit modifier

[image]